# Vuetify - How to do label text left and text field right on form

Tags: forms, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to left label and right text field in vuetify.

In vuetify homepage usage, it's label and text field form is not my requirement.

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="firstname"
    label="First name">
</v-text-field>
```

I want the left label and right text field on form in vuetify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using v-subheader? As there is no such prop that you can set the textfield label out of the textfield container and align to left side.

```
  <v-layout row>
    <v-flex xs1>
      <v-subheader>Label here</v-subheader>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex xs2>
      <v-text-field
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
```

Codepen link [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LoOpwx?&editable=true&editors=101).

Comment: Thank you for your concerning and codepen link of example. It is my requirement. It's good. But is there some horizontal alignment? You suggested code - It would be better that the label and text field will be horizontal alignment.

Comment: No sadly i din't found any property that could set the label and text field in horizontal alignment.Henceforth i suggested you the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cant comment because I have no enough reputation. You can horizontal align by adding class="my-4" in your v-subheader. the greater the number the lower the label

I used Riddhi sample below:

```
<v-layout row>
    <v-flex xs1>
      <v-subheader class="my-4">Label</v-subheader>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex xs2>
      <v-text-field
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-flex>
 </v-layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

vuetify version 2.5.8

```
<v-row dense>
  <v-col cols="12" md="2">
    <v-list-item-content>Label</v-list-item-content>
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="12" md="10">
    <v-text-field dense clearable></v-text-field>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify has been updated since, and the v-flex answer doesn't work under the new grid system. The Cols method will work but it's difficult to align the labels with the fields and make it look good.

I've achieved the result I wanted by doing the following.

Use the 'prepend' slot:

```
<v-text-field
  class="my-text-field"
  solo
  dense
  v-model="actor.name"
>
  <template v-slot:prepend>
    <div class="body-2">Display Name</div>
  </template>
</v-text-field>
```

Use CSS to make a class of .my-text-field

```
.my-text-field .v-input__prepend-outer {
  min-width: 140px; /* Change the width to your desired value */
}
```